# Proving Bijection to a function containing relative complement set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=P(\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}), B=\{x\in A: |x|=2\}, C=\{x\in A: |x|=5\}$
$f:B\to C, \ \ f(x)=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} -x$, $\ $when "-" denotes the relative complement
Prove:
1. $f$ is injection
2. $f$  is surjection

I'm kindda new to set theory so don't really know how to properly proof this so any help will be appreciated. I did succeed in finding $f^{-1}(x)$ and proving it, but those two clauses left me frustrated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An injection has unique outputs for each input. To prove a function is injective, usually you show that if two inputs, $x_1, x_2 \in B$, have the same output, $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$.

For injectivity: Suppose $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Given $\alpha \in x_1$, since $x_1 \subset A$, $\alpha \in A$ and thus $\alpha \in A - x_1 = f(x_1)$. Since $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, it follows that $\alpha \in f(x_2) = A - x_2$. Therefore, because $\alpha \in A$, $\alpha \in x_2$. So $x_2 \subseteq x_1$. Using a similar argument, we can see that $x_1 \subseteq x_2$ and the $x_1 = x_2$.

A surjection has range equal to codomain. To prove a function is surjective, for any given $y \in C$ find an $x \in B$ such that $f(x) = y$. This involves using your inverse ($x = f^{-1}(y)$).

For surjectivity: for a given $y \in C$ just use your inverse to obtain $x \in B$.

Comment: Yes I know the definition, showing them is the problem :) especially with mathematic notations.

Comment: I fleshed out my answer.